# Log4j printing escaped JSON string instead of JSON object

Tags: json, logging, log4j2

I am using Log4j 2.13 and have used a JSONLayout with `objectMessageAsJsonObject` set to `true`.

When an escaped JSON string is logged, the string is printed as it is instead of being deserialized into a JSON object.

For instance, the following log statement :-

```
log.info("{\n\"hello\": \"world\",\n\"testing\":\"123\",\n\"msg\": \"stringified json text\"\n}");
```

leads to the following log event :-

```
{
   "timeMillis":1605794041490,
   "level":"INFO","loggerName":"xyz",
   "message":"{\n\"hello\": \"world\",\n\"testing\":\"123\",\n\"msg\": \"stringified json text\"\n}",
   "endOfBatch":false,
   "parameterCount":0,
   "loggerFqcn":"org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger",
   "formattedMessage":"{\n\"hello\": \"world\",\n\"testing\":\"123\",\n\"msg\": \"stringified json text\"\n}",
   "threadPriority":5,
   "threadId":51,
   "contextMap": {
      "RequestId":"123"
   }
}
```

As per [the documentation on JSONLayout](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#JSONLayout), using `objectMessageAsJsonObject` would lead to the log content being interpreted as a JSON object.

How can I get Log4j to print this string as unescaped JSON?